# Algorithms for interactive visualizations, like spreading, sizing, physics, etc

Tags: algorithm, canvas, svg, visualization, data-visualization

Is there any book or site that describes the algorithms that people use in building interactive visualizations, like:

- Spacing stuff evenly
- Sizing options, e.g. according to popularity
- Applying physics like gravity and friction
- Organic growth etc.

I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I once read this survey of graph drawing algorithm: [Algorithms for Drawing Graphs: an Annotated Bibliography](http://www.cs.brown.edu/people/rt/papers/gdbiblio.pdf). Very extensive introduction of all kinds of techniques to draw graphs, including maintaining the aesthetics of the visualization.

I also read several papers on how to draw physics-based auto-spacing graphs a while ago but I don't remember where I saved them. Will update the answer soon. --> Here are a few:

[Accelerated Force Computation for Physics-Based Information Visualization](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=769928)

[Graph Drawing by Force-directed Placement](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.13.8444)

If you like scholar-type publications, have a look at the conferences such as VIS, VAST and InfoVis.